Null key returned for cache operation and Parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure to use '-parameters' compiler flag
On updating our application to Spring Boot 3.2.5 and Spring framework 6.1.6. we are getting following Errors.
ERROR c.a.s.t.c.e.ControllerExceptionHandler - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.lang.String] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.

ERROR c.a.s.t.c.e.ControllerExceptionHandler - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation  caches=[cacheExample] | key='#cacheKey' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='true']. If you are using named parameters, ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation  caches=[cacheExample] | key='#cacheKey' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='true']. If you are using named parameters, ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.

It seams, it is asking to compile(java) code with '-parameters' flag. So for that, I have followed the directions on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention:
I have added:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}

Even i had tried adding following mentioned in Thread: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31729
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    configure(options) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    }
}

Nothing works for me. But yes, on adding parameter indexes like key="#p0" is working for me. Actually, I want to use parameter name instead of parameter index.
I have used following configurations/tools:

springBootVersion= 3.2.5
springFrameworkVersion= 6.1.6
Java= 17.0.5
gradle= 8.7
Vscode= 1.88.1

Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

See my answer on Name for argument of type 'java.lang.String' not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection.

This works for me:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}


In the maven compiler configuration in pom.xml add the following
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Support for Spring 6.1.x -->
        <parameters>true</parameters>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- --- --- --- --- --- -->
        <release>${java.version}</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

